# How to do an empty array

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I have this question here

> Once a player has drawn the top card from the deck, they must discard it.
>
> Given a deck of cards, return a new deck containing all the cards except the first from the original deck.
>
> Note: The new array returned is one element shorter than the original, except when the deck has no cards. Then the array returned must be empty.

So basically I have to make a new array thats the same as the old array minus the card at index 0. The issue im having is when I have to put an empty array and IntelliJ keeps throwing a NegativeArraySizeException.

```java
public String[] discardTopCard(String[] remainingDeck) {
    String[] newHand = new String[remainingDeck.length - 1];
    String[] emptyArray = new String[] {};
    int k = 0;

    if (remainingDeck.length == 0 || remainingDeck.length == 1) {
        return emptyArray;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < remainingDeck.length; i++) {
        newHand[k] = remainingDeck[i];
        k++;
    }
    return newHand;
}
```

this is my current code.

I've also tried this and just setting it to null

```java
public String[] discardTopCard(String[] remainingDeck) {
    String[] newHand = new String[remainingDeck.length - 1];
    int k = 0;

    if (remainingDeck.length == 0 || remainingDeck.length == 1) {
        return remainingDeck;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < remainingDeck.length; i++) {
        newHand[k] = remainingDeck[i];
        k++;
    }
    return newHand;
}
```

Comment: You should look into `ArrayList` and other collections, as they are not fixed-size like arrays are.

Comment: Don't create `newHand` until you know you need to.

Comment: Won't the second version fail to remove the last card?  And have the same problem with trying to remove an item from a empty deck?

Comment: You should create the new ```Array``` after the ```if``` block. At this point you konw that the length is greater than 1. Otherwise you would try to create an ```Array``` with length -1. This would be illegal,

Comment: An empty array is usually composed of all `null` values.  It might also be a zero length array, depending on how you spec it out.  The suggestion to use an `ArrayList` is on point, much easier.

Comment: Can you add the exception stacktrace?

Comment: Please edit the question to show errors (as text), if any, both compiler errors and run-time errors.

Comment: Look at this statement: `String[] newHand = new String[remainingDeck.length - 1];`  if `remainingDeck` is already empty, this will result in an attempt to create `newHand` with a length of negative one.  What happens if you try `String[] newHand = new String[Math.max (0,remainingDeck.length - 1)];`

Comment: A good software developer will know how to use a debugger, which is generally included in an IDE. This is a good case for learning how to use or getting practice using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with a new array that is only part of an existing on, I would recommend to use an existing method: [`java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T%5B%5D,int,int))

Example:

```java
private static final String[] EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = new String[0];

public String[] discardTopCard(String[] remainingDeck) {
    int length = remainingDeck.length;
    if (length < 2) {
        return EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY;
    }
    
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(remainingDeck, 1, length);
}
```

I declared the empty string array as constant outside the method, because it is immutable and it's not necessary to create more than one instance in the whole program.

Both cases, empty input array and input array of lenght 1 will have the same result: an empty array.

Also note that usage of `length` in the `copyOfRange` method is OK because there it acts as "to"-index and not as number of elements to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Or, even simpler:

```
public String[] discardTopCard(String[] deck) {
    if (deck.length > 1) 
        deck = Arrays.copyOfRange(deck, 1, deck.length);
    return deck;
}
```

Comment: If `deck.length == 1` ?

Comment: public String[] discardTopCard(String[] deck) {
  if (deck.length > 0) 
   deck = Arrays.copyOfRange(deck, 1, deck.length);
  return deck;
 }

Comment: You're right ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public String[] discardTopCard(String[] deck) {

    if (deck.length == 0) {
        return deck;
    }

    String[] smallerDeck = new String[deck.length - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < smallerDeck.length; i++) {
        smallerDeck[i] = deck[i];
    }

    return smallerDeck;
}
```